# Laravel /broadcasting/auth Always forbidden with 403 Error

Tags: vue.js, channel, laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-events

I tried many solutions but no one works for me

I've installed Laravel echo and pusher js and Pusher/Pusher

#bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,

});
```

#.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=my_id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=my_key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=my_secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```

my event file NewMessage

```
class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('messages.'. $this->message->to);
    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ["message" => $this->message];
    }
}
```

channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Vue App JS code

```
mounted(){
            Echo.private(`messages${this.user.id}`)
            .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
                this.handleIncoming(e.message)
            });
          },
methods:{
      saveNewMessage(msg){
                this.messages.push(msg);
            },
            handleIncoming(message){
                if(this.selectedContact && message.from == this.selectedContact.id ){
                    this.saveNewMessage(message);
                    return;
                }
                alert(message.text);
            }
          }
```

Api.php

```
Route::post('/conversation/send', 'Api\ContactController@sendNewMessage');
```

Contact Controller

```
public function sendNewMessage(Request $request)
    {
       $message = Message::create([
            'from' => $request->sender_id,
            'to' => $request->receiver_id,
            'text' => $request->text
        ]);

        broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
        return response()->json($message);
    }
```

I also read the official documentation everything is going good but I didn't figure out why, it's a throwing error. Have any idea?

Comment: Have you uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in your `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yes, I un-commented inside the provider.

Comment: Have a look here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-broadcastingauth-always-fails-with-403-error

Comment: Already watched this post bro

Comment: Since they've got it working there, I suggest trying out the above steps on a clean install and then figuring out the differences between your current implementation and that one.

Comment: What is the main solution they are highlighting, I am not getting the exact solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226703/discussion-between-hadiniazi-and-afaan-bilal).

Answer (score 1):

I figure out why it is every time shows auth forbidden or doesn't display auth

Solution:
you need to double-check your PUSHER_APP_KEY because if it is not set correctly, it will through error because our stream  not connected with pusher

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY="PUT KEY HERE"
```

If you are very sure that your app key is correct then go to the Network tab and click on your pusher app key which like e70ewesdsdssew0
If it is displaying the result like this

```
{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"131139.31305364\",\"activity_timeout\":120}"}
```

your API key is good
if it not correct it will display an error like this

```
{"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":4001,"message":"App key 3fdsfdfsdfsd not in this cluster. Did you forget to specify the cluster?"}}
```

Also, don't forget to put the cluster key

```
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```